# How to count cells that contain text from a certain list

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I use a sheet to enter names of people who work at certain shifts, for example
on column A, the people that work from 8am to 4pm,
on column B the people that work from 4pm till midnight
on column C and beyond, special shifts
etc

This table is A1:N24 and it contains titles (of shifts), names of workers and some special notes, about each worker.

On column R I have a list of workers that I use for data validation/drop down lists, to make the entry of workers' names easier

My question is how I can count the number of cells on the A1:N24 table that contain only names from the R column list, leaving out the title cells and the special notes cells.

The COUNTIF function seems like a logical choice but I couldn't make it work with a range of criteria, my workers list. Maybe the DCOUNTA function could be of use in my case?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `DCountA function` seems to be ok...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (entered as an array formula)

```
=COUNT(MATCH(A1:N24,R:R,0))
```

How it works:

- `MATCH(A1:N24,R:R,0)` returns an array of values where the entry in `A1:N24` is found, and `#N/A` errors where its not
- `COUNT( )` counts the Numbers in that array, ie the number of matching values